# creating a list (of identical points) from a collection of points generated from an input list of points in python

Tags: python

Better to explain the problem by example:

**Given input list1 and list2**:

```
list1 = [0,1,2,3,4]
list2 = [[0,1],[1],[2,3],[2],[4]]
```

```
    list1[0] = 0 --> [0,1] of list2[0] (meaning that  element 0 of list1 is mapped to element 0 and 1 of list2)
    list1[1] = 1 --> [1] of list2[1]   (meaning that  element 1 is mapped to element 1)
    list1[2] = 2 --> [2,3] of list2[2] (meaning that  element 2 is mapped to element 2 and 3)
    list1[3] = 3 --> [2] of list2[3]   (meaning that  element 3 is mapped to element 2)
    list1[4] = 4 --> [4] of list2[4]   (meaning that  element 4 is mapped to element 4 itself)
```

**So, from list1 and list2, i want to get like list this:**

```
outputlist=
[  [[0], [0]], 
   [[1], [0]], 
   [[2], [2]], 
   [[3], [2]],
   [[4], [4]]
]
```

```
    outputlist shows that:
    1st element is identical to itself
    2nd element is identical to first element
    3rd element is identical to itself
    4th element is identical to 3rd element
    5th element is identical to itself
```

*Basically this is a mapping showing that which elements of list1 are identical.*

Comment: Define **identical**

Comment: Also: why are the output elements lists? e.g why isn't `1` mappred to `[0, 1]`?

Comment: What's the exact issue here?

Comment: @Pynchia identical means: element 0 of list1 equal to element 0 present in list2.

Comment: @NunoPalma: issue is how to get outputlist list from list1 and list2. For example, list1[0] is mapped to list2[0] => 0 is identical to 0 and 1 element (present in list2[0]), and so on. This way I want to find which element or entries of list1 are identical?

Comment: What have you done to try to solve this? What are you doing with those mappings? As @Pynchia said, you need to **clearly define** what _identical_ means here.

Comment: @Pynchia : 1 mapped to [0,1] is given. It means 1 (element of list1) is same as element 0 and element 1 of list2.  So through some mapping applied on 1 gives 0 and 1 stored as list [0,1]. Similarly mapping is applied on other list1 entries to a get list for each entry of list1.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile : to be honest I don't know how to do it. Mapping is helping me to know which entries of list1 are _equivalent_ (not identical; sorry for the big mistake). So, from list1 and list2, I infer that 0 is equivalent to 1, 2 is equivalent to 3, and 4 has no equivalent. Which is what indicated by outputlist.

Comment: @snano Ah yes, _equivalent_ versus _identical_ is quite an important distinction. Do you need your mapping to go only in a particular direction (Do you need to go only list1 -> list2 or vice-versa)? Can you explain what the mapping is being used for in your program?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile : Mapping is vice versa. Mapping is just an operation (addition, subtraction, or multiplication, etc ) which when applied on each element of list1 generates again the elements of list1 stored in list2. This way I come to know about equivalent entries of list1.

Comment: @snano You wrote list1 twice, is that correct? What I meant is do you need to find the corresponding element in list1 given an element in list2, or find the element in list2 from an element in list1, or both ways?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile : yes, both ways. Let me clear it in more detail: I applied say 3 operations(or mapping) on 0 (element of list1) and got two elements, 0 and 1 (3rd operation gave me other element not present in list1), which are stored in list2 as  [0,1].

Comment: What's the criteria for defining identical values? For instance, the first element of list2 contains two values. How do you compare any of these with list1?